# Custom base_site.html not working in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, nitrousio

I am using [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io/) for playing with the Django framework. In [tutorial 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02) is shown how to change the base_site.html template. I've added in the TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( ) a new line:

> 'home/action/workspace/mysite/templates',

And in base_site.html I changed the site name title of Django Administration into Administration:

> {% trans 'Administration' %}

But I still see no changes on the website. I've tried different TEMPLATE_DIRS like:

> '~/workspace/mysite/templates',
>
> 'home/action/workspace/mysite/',
>
> 'home/action/workspace/mysite/templates/',

And restarting the server. But I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note that this answer was written before the `TEMPLATES` setting was introduced in Django 1.8.**

The tutorial says you should create an `admin` subdirectory inside your template directory, and put your template inside that.

Try with `base_site.html` in `/home/action/workspace/mysite/templates/admin` and with

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/action/workspace/mysite/templates',
)
```

Note the slash before `/home/...` and the trailing comma to make it a tuple.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mentioned it, but I have copied the base_site.html to `home/action/workspace/mysite/templates/admin` and I also changed the TEMPLATE_DIRS into `home/action/workspace/mysite/templates/admin`...but without result.

Comment: Thanks, the slash before `home` is the solution! Note that the slash behind `template` is not necessary.

Comment: Glad that worked :) I've moved the comment to the answer, and removed the trailing slash.