# How do I customize the admin page in Django 1.7?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, python-3.4, django-1.7

I've been learning from the Django Documentation and have stumbled upon a road block in the section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel

My files are arranged as:

```
mysite/

    mysite/

        __pycache__/
            ...

        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    polls/

        __pycache__/
            ...

        migrations/
            ...

        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py

    templates/
        admin/
            base_site.html

    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

I have modified the text in the file base_site.html to "Polls App" but the admin site continues to display "Django Administration".

PS: I'm using Win8

Comment: Same issue for me with python 2.7.8, django 1.7 under Linux... Just started pythoning and djangoing, not best start conditions... Found the solution in another question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django 1.7 - updating base\_site.html not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727687/django-1-7-updating-base-site-html-not-working)

Comment: Yes, that did the job! :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place that templates folder in the project directory, not on the same level as the project as it currently is.

So place it under mysite/templates and you should be close.

EDIT: Actually, put the templates folder under your application so that it is Polls/templates

Comment: Nope, placing it within the application directory doesn't help either! :(

Answer (score 0):

I have it at the same place as you, right under the project root. Make sure that `django.contrib.admin` is defined before your `polls` app in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Yes it is!

`code`
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)
`code`